# Time Reserval Symmetry Operator on Spin Orbit Coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry, spin-orbit

Suppose the spin orbit coupling term is written below.
$$H_{soc} = \xi L\cdot\sigma$$
where, $\xi$ is the strength of the spin orbit coupling, $L$ and $\sigma$ are angular momentum and pauli matrix operators respectively.

The exchange potential term is written in the following.
$$m_z \times \sigma$$
where, $m_z$ is a magnitude of exchange potential and $\sigma$ is the pauli matrix

When the time reversal symmetry operator is applied onto these two terms respectively, why does the spin orbit coupling term change the sign; while, does not the exchange potential term?

Comment: Spin orbit does not change sign under time reversal that's the whole point of Kramers theorem.

Comment: @Mauricio Thank you for the reply. In other words, if I multiply the spin-orbit coupling term in the followings: $$e^{i\pi J_y}\langle d_{xy}\uparrow|\xi L\cdot\sigma|p_{z}\downarrow\rangle$$; where $$e^{i\pi J_y}$$ is the time reversal operator, this term should change the sign. Am I correct?

If so, how to choose $J_y$, the y-component of the angular momentum operator, for different term? I think that this operator varies with different orbital $p_z$,$d_{xy}$. Thank you.